# Redshift, Find the level distribution of each items (Total number of item per level)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The question is updated!!

I have a database that stores customer item upgrade. I have DateTime and upgraded level. 
When customer upgrade item in day 1 and again on day 5, I cannot see any information between Day1-Day5

Example data: (Upgrade table)

```
 day              customer    items        levels
01/01/2019           a          item1          0
01/01/2019           b          item1          0
02/01/2019           a          item1          1
03/01/2019           b          item1          1
04/01/2019           a          item1          2
05/01/2019           b          item1          2
05/01/2019           c          item1          0
06/01/2019           b          item1          3
07/01/2019           d          item2          0
08/01/2019           NULL       NULL          NULL
09/01/2019           b          item1          4
10/01/2019           NULL       NULL          NULL
11/10/2019           b          item1         5
11/10/2019           a          item1         3
11/10/2019           a          item1         4
```

Example data: (daily table for a user)

```
 day              time-spent      
01/01/2019           11       
02/01/2019           34        
03/01/2019           56        
04/01/2019           78       
11/01/2019           3         
14/01/2019           13
22/01/2019           30
```

My challange is find the total number of item for in each level
so How many `Level 0` `item-1` I have per day:

```
01/01/2019     2            
02/01/2019     1      
03/01/2019     0     
04/01/2019     0      
05/01/2019     1             
06/01/2019     1     
07/01/2019     1      
08/01/2019     1     
09/01/2019     1      
10/01/2019     1      
11/10/2019     1
```

How many `Level 1` item-1 I have per day?

```
01/01/2019     0            
02/01/2019     1      
03/01/2019     2     
04/01/2019     1      
05/01/2019     0             
06/01/2019     0     
07/01/2019     0      
08/01/2019     0     
09/01/2019     0      
10/01/2019     0      
11/10/2019     0
```

for all twenty levels per item!
(I need to find the level of item distributions!)

What I tried this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
           SELECT date(timestamp) day,
                  user_id,
                  item_id,
                  level,
-- Left join the daily table and get last value of an item per customers
                  last_value(level) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY day
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) level_r
           FROM daily d -- I have a calendar dates from and all customers in this table 
                  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT user_id,
                      date(TIMESTAMP) t,
                      item_id,
                      level,
                      RANK()
                      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id,date(timestamp), item_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC ) transaction_rank
               FROM updated 
               WHERE item_id
             ) u ON u.user_id = d.user_id AND u.t = d.day AND transaction_rank = 1
           GROUP BY
             1, 2, 3, 4)
```

but the problem is, it works if I have one customer because of null values bu if you have multiple customers it does not work.

How can I found the level distribution for items?

**EDIT:** I wanted to add some more information to make clearer. If no one changes their item level the previous day I need to know the day after as well.

I need to know how many levels of an item I have from any chosen date to the previous whole time

**EDIT-2:** I do not need to join the upgrade table to daily. I need to see al values of upgrade table result in generate_series type but when I create generate seres I have an eror

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you want as a result set and how it is calculated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the question updated!

Comment: @Axis to be clearer please share both the tables data (daily, upgrade table) and the expected output clearly. This seems to be doable but I am having difficulty understanding..

Comment: @Axis please send the result output you desire for more clarity.

Comment: Please check above

Comment: @Axis can you create a table of dates (GENERATE_SERIES seems to be unavailable).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have at least one row per day, then this seems like aggregation:

```
select timestamp::date,
       sum( (level = 1)::int ) as level_1,
       sum( (level = 2)::int ) as level_2,
       . . . 
       sum( (level = 20)::int ) as level_20
from daily
group by timestamp::date
order by timestamp::date;
```

Comment: daily data keep customers daily data, not any level data when I join the tables I can only see level upgrade dates so when I use sum I can see sum of those days but if I do not upgrade my item I have still that level over days as well

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```
Select * from 
(Select Day,items,levels,count(*) from dataa group by 
               day,items,levels )
 pivot (count(*) for levels in (0,1,2,3,4,5)) order by day,items;
```

[image]

Comment: I can see each level in the day already I need to see in other days even though not any level update. I need total items each day with the total number per levels

Comment: Did you try to run the above query

Comment: Did the o/p match the requirement

Comment: Can you tell how you got `02/01/2019     1 ` in the `Level 0 item-1`  again `06/01/2019` is 1 but I see no level 0 on that day

Comment: @Fact, The first you commented at wrong place so I could not see your comment. Yes this is the question! I need to know how many level 0 I have in whole data so if you check previous rows, b upgraded item so I have only customer a item 0. if no one change their levels I need to know all dates. This is the distribution.

Comment: But your query is still unclear i think its a made up query how come the day 2 has count as 1 of level 0 when there is no level 0 present in the data for that same day

Comment: pivot in redshift?

Comment: If pivot doesnt work you can specify sum(case when level=0 then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when level=1...) etc. Youll be able to receive the same o/p as above

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by building a base query, that gives us the current level of each customer on each and every day.

This works by recovering all available days in the table, then all prior records to each day, and finally aggregating to compute the current level of each `(customer, item)` tuple.

The underlying assumption is that that the level of a tuple cannot decrease (this is consistent with your sample data).

```
select
    d.day,
    t.customer, 
    t.items,
    max(t.levels) max_level
from 
    (select distinct day from mytable) d
    left join mytable t on t.day <= d.day
group by 
    d.day, 
    t.customer, 
    t.items
```

---

From there on, it's quite easy to generate the required output, by adding another level of (conditional) aggregation.

This query gives you the distribution of customers of `item1` per date across levels 1 to 5:

```
select 
    day,
    sum( (max_level = 0)::int ) level0,
    sum( (max_level = 1)::int ) level1,
    sum( (max_level = 2)::int ) level2,
    sum( (max_level = 2)::int ) level3,
    sum( (max_level = 4)::int ) level4,
    sum( (max_level = 5)::int ) level5
from (
    select
        d.day,
        t.customer, 
        t.items,
        max(t.levels) max_level
    from 
        (select distinct day from mytable) d
        left join mytable t on t.day <= d.day
    group by 
        d.day, 
        t.customer, 
        t.items
) x
where items = 'item1'
group by day
order by day
```

Yields:

```
| day                      | level0 | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | level5 |
| ------------------------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z | 0      | 2      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z | 0      | 1      | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 2      | 2      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      |
| 2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 1      | 0      |
| 2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 1      | 0      |
| 2019-11-10T00:00:00.000Z | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 1      | 1      |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ocEi841YRzTLmoHjpPSiLc/1)**

Comment: @Axis: does this answer properly responds to your question? As far as tested, it generates the correct result for your sample data.

Comment: unfortunately same result that I have.

Comment: *unfortunately same result that I have*: I don’t understand what you mean. This query returns the results you expect as described by you as *How many Level 0 item-1 I have per day?* and *How many Level 1 item-1 I have per day?*. It also gives you the ability to get the results for all levels at once, as you requested. So: what is wrong?